# flora city stickers joptionpane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am currently working on an assignment for my Java class. It requires us to change some code around in a file to add joptionpane dialog boxes in instead of the fields already there. The following is the exact wording of the assignment:

Look through the source code for the Flora. java file. Insert comment marks (//) at the beginning of all lines involving any of the message boxes, except for the MessageBox declaration statements. Directly underneath the lines that are commented out, insert new code to generate JOptionPane dialog boxes that replace the message boxes. Use the same titles, prompts, and buttons. Do not forget to import the necessary Swing packages.

I am having trouble figuring out how to add a JOptionPane box in. I imported the swing for the joptionpane but I  need assistance setting it up for the boxes

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Flora extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
   MessageBox savedBox;
   MessageBox errorBox;
   DataOutputStream output;
   //Construct components
   Panel dataFields = new Panel();
   Panel firstRow = new Panel();
   Panel secondRow = new Panel();
   Panel thirdRow = new Panel();
   Panel fourthRow = new Panel();
   Panel fifthRow = new Panel();
   Panel sixthRow = new Panel();
   Panel buttonArea= new Panel();

   Button newSticker = new Button("New Sticker");
   Button renewal = new Button("Renewal");

   //Label vinLabel = new Label("Enter Vehicle VIN number:    ");
      //TextField vin = new TextField(20);
   //Label yearLabel = new Label("Year:   ");
      //TextField year = new TextField(4);
   //Label makeLabel = new Label("Make:               ");
      //TextField make = new TextField(10);
   //Label modelLabel = new Label("Model:");
      //TextField model = new TextField(10);
   //Label firstNameLabel = new Label("Enter First Name:       ");
      //TextField firstName = new TextField(15);
   //Label lastNameLabel = new Label("Enter Last Name:");
      //TextField lastName = new TextField(20);
   //Label addressLabel = new Label("Enter Flora Address:");
      //TextField address = new TextField (35);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Flora window = new Flora();
      window.setTitle("Flora City Stickers");
      window.setSize(450, 250);
      window.setVisible(true);
   }

   public Flora()
   {
     //Set background and layout managers
     setBackground(Color.magenta);
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dataFields.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        FlowLayout rowSetup = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,5,2);
           firstRow.setLayout(rowSetup);
           secondRow.setLayout(rowSetup);
           thirdRow.setLayout(rowSetup);
           fourthRow.setLayout(rowSetup);
           fifthRow.setLayout(rowSetup);
           sixthRow.setLayout(rowSetup);
        buttonArea.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     //Add fields to rows
     firstRow.add(vinLabel);
     firstRow.add(yearLabel);
     firstRow.add(makeLabel);
     firstRow.add(modelLabel);

     secondRow.add(vin);
     secondRow.add(year);
     secondRow.add(make);
     secondRow.add(model);

     thirdRow.add(firstNameLabel);
     thirdRow.add(lastNameLabel);

     fourthRow.add(firstName);
     fourthRow.add(lastName);

     fifthRow.add(addressLabel);

     sixthRow.add(address);

     //Add rows to panel
     dataFields.add(firstRow);
     dataFields.add(secondRow);
     dataFields.add(thirdRow);
     dataFields.add(fourthRow);
     dataFields.add(fifthRow);
     dataFields.add(sixthRow);

     //Add buttons to panel
     buttonArea.add(newSticker);
     buttonArea.add(renewal);

     //Add panels to frame
     add(dataFields, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     add(buttonArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

     //Add functionality to buttons
     newSticker.addActionListener(this);
     renewal.addActionListener(this);

     //Open the file
     try
     {
        output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Sticker.dat"));
     }
     catch(IOException c)
     {
        System.exit(1);
     }

     //Construct window listener
     addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter()
           {
               public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
               {
                  System.exit(0);
               }
           }
      );
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      String arg = e.getActionCommand();
  String code;
  if (arg == "New Sticker")
     code = "N";
  else
     code = "R";

  if (
        (vin.getText().compareTo("")<1)       ||
        (year.getText().compareTo("")<1)      ||
        (make.getText().compareTo("")<1)      ||
        (model.getText().compareTo("")<1)     ||
        (firstName.getText().compareTo("")<1) ||
        (lastName.getText().compareTo("")<1)  ||
        (address.getText().compareTo("")<1)
     )
  {

     errorBox = new MessageBox(this, "Data Entry Error", "You must complete all fields.");
     errorBox.setVisible(true);
  }
  else
  {
  try
  {
     output.writeUTF(code);
     output.writeUTF(vin.getText());
     output.writeUTF(year.getText());
     output.writeUTF(make.getText());
     output.writeUTF(model.getText());
     output.writeUTF(firstName.getText());
     output.writeUTF(lastName.getText());
     output.writeUTF(address.getText());

         savedBox = new MessageBox(this, "Data Submitted", "The vehicle information has been saved.");
         savedBox.setVisible(true);
      }
      catch(IOException c)
      {
         System.exit(1);
      }
      clearFields();
      }
   }

   public void clearFields()
   {
      //Clear fields and reset the focus
      vin.setText("");
      year.setText("");
      make.setText("");
      model.setText("");
      firstName.setText("");
      lastName.setText("");
      address.setText("");
      vin.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

I know they want the original boxes commented out and I think I did that but I am not sure I have gotten everything. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  In general, questions of the form "please review my code and make it work" are off-topic for SO.  This is especially true for homework, where the whole point is for you to do the work and learn from the experience.

Comment: I didn't intend for it to look like I wasnted someone to do it for me. I just am extremely new to java and I am being kind of thrown into it blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions state **"Insert comment marks (//) at the beginning of all lines involving any of the message boxes, except for the MessageBox declaration statements"**. You've commented out all the `Jlabels` and `JTextFields`. I don't think that is part of the instruction.

You're looking for all the `saveBox` and `errorBox` EXCEPT the declarations `MessageBox savedBox;` `MessageBox errorBox;`

So all these are what you are looking to comment out.

```
savedBox = new MessageBox(this, "Data Submitted", "The vehicle information has been saved.");
saveBox.setVisible(true);

errorBox = new MessageBox(this, "Data Entry Error", "You must complete all fields.");
errorBox.setVisible(true);
```

And I believe you should replace them with a `JOptionPane`

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Data Entry Error", "You must complete all fields.");
```

Comment: It probably would have helped if I had read everything through -_- So do I create separate joptionpane lines for the message boxes or will what you provided cover both?

Comment: "Directly underneath the lines that are commented out, insert new code to generate JOptionPane dialog boxes that replace the message boxes."

Comment: I believe for ever pair of `errorBox = new MessageBox(this, "Data Entry Error", "You must complete all fields.");
errorBox.setVisible(true);` just replace it with the according `JOptionPane`

Comment: JOptionPane jpane1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Data Entry Error","You must complete all fields.");

I input that just under the commented out stuff and Textpad isn't recognizing it. I compiled and it errored saying incompatible types and put a carot under the first (

Comment: Whatever the messages are, insert them appropriately.

Comment: I get the same error when compiling. JOptionPane is not turning blue in Textpad when I input it. Did I call the wrong swing in the beginning?

Comment: C:\Users\James\Desktop\Chapter08\Flora.java:155: error: incompatible types
         JOptionPane jPane1 = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data Entry Error", "You must complete all fields.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

Comment: try this `new JOptionPane().showMessageDialog(this, "Data Entry Error", "You must complete all fields.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`

Comment: becuase `showMessageDialog()` returns `void` and void is not equal  to a `JOptionPane`